# Is it possible for Apple Watch to be notified with vibration when iPhone is unlocked?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, unlock

Is it possible for Apple Watch to be notified with vibration when iPhone is unlocked? My iPhone app needs to send vibration alerts to Apple Watch under some user actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages from the iPhone using the WatchConnectivity framework and you can use Haptic feedback to notify the user, but the system won't display notifications on the Watch when the iPhone is unlocked.